# using sed with variables defined in 2 arrays

Tags: sed, array

I have followed the very many posts on this site regarding the subject but I am still clearly doing something wrong...

My goal is to define values in two different arrays, then use sed to search a string of text defined in the first array with that of the second array.

Code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define variables
defaultdirs=( Templates Documents Music Pictures Videos )
customdirs=( custom\/templates custom\/documents custom\/music custom\/pictures custom\/videos )

# replace text strings
for index in ${!defaultdirs[*]}
    do
    echo ${defaultdirs[$index]} will become ${customdirs[$index]}
    sed -i 's/${defaultdirs[$index]}/${customdirs[$index]}/g' ~/Desktop/scripts/test_replace.txt
done
```

echo outputs the right strings, but sed is not be getting the right information as the text file remains unchanged.

Thoughts?

For reference, this is the contents of test_replace.txt

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Variables aren't replaced in single-quoted strings...

Comment: @Shawn, if I use double-quotes there is an error similar to the below for each iteration of the loop: sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: single quoted strings don't have variables in them expanded.

Second problem: As-is, the slashes in your replacement will break the `s///g` command after fixing the first problem. Use a different delimiter for `s`.

Third (lesser) problem: You're running `sed` multiple times over the same file, which isn't very efficient, and the `-i` option for in-place editing is non-standard and different implementations that do provide it act differently (The common case people run into issues with is that the GNU version doesn't require a argument, but the Mac OS version does). When wanting to edit a file and save changes, it's usually better to use a dedicated file editor like `ed` or `ex`.

Doing it all with one `ed` invocation instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# define variables
defaultdirs=(Templates Documents Music Pictures Videos)
customdirs=(custom/templates custom/documents custom/music custom/pictures custom/videos)

# replace text strings
(for index in ${!defaultdirs[*]}; do
     echo "${defaultdirs[$index]} will become ${customdirs[$index]}" >&2
     echo "g/${defaultdirs[$index]}/s|${defaultdirs[$index]}|${customdirs[$index]}|g"
 done;
 echo w) | ed -s test_replace.txt
```

---

Alternative that sends the `X will become Y` messages to standard output instead of standard error, and runs `ed` in a [coprocess](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc), with individual commands redirected to its input instead of using a pipeline:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# define variables
defaultdirs=(Templates Documents Music Pictures Videos)
customdirs=(custom/templates custom/documents custom/music custom/pictures custom/videos)

coproc ED { ed -s test_replace.txt; } 2>/dev/null

# replace text strings
for index in ${!defaultdirs[*]}; do
     echo "${defaultdirs[$index]} will become ${customdirs[$index]}"
     echo "g/${defaultdirs[$index]}/s|${defaultdirs[$index]}|${customdirs[$index]}|g" >&${ED[1]}
done
printf '%s\n' w q >&${ED[1]}
wait $ED_PID
```

Comment: worked a treat, thanks for the answer and more importantly the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all the `s`ubstitute commands into one input to `sed` as well:

```
for index in ${!defaultdirs[*]}
  do   echo "s#${defaultdirs[$index]}#${customdirs[$index]}#g"
  done | sed -f- ~/Desktop/scripts/test_replace.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as [Shawn has already pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577955/116858), is that you create a `sed` script with a syntax error.  The syntax error comes from the fact that you try to use `/` in an `s` command that uses that same character as a delimiter.

You *try* to counteract this by escaping the `/` in the strings in the `customdirs` array, but you would need `\\/` to actually insert an escaping `\` in the string.

Instead, here's a different approach:

```bash
find_strings=( Templates Documents Music Pictures Videos )
replace_strings=( custom/templates custom/documents custom/music custom/pictures custom/videos )

set -- "${find_strings[@]}"

sed_stmts=( )
for replace_string in "${replace_strings[@]}"; do
   # sed_stmts+=( -e 's,\("$HOME/\)'"$1"'",\1'"$replace_string"'",' )

    # simpler, but less precise:
    #    sed_stmts+=( -e "s,$1,$replace_string," )
    # alternatively:
    #    sed_stmts+=( -e "s/${1//\//\\/}/${replace_string//\//\\/}/" )

    shift
done

sed "${sed_stmts[@]}" test_replace.txt >new-test_replace.txt
```

I've also taken the liberty to make the substitutions a bit more reliable by also matching the `"$HOME/` prefix string and the final `"`.

This will end up calling `sed` like so:

```
sed -e 's,\("$HOME/\)Templates",\1custom/templates",' -e 's,\("$HOME/\)Documents",\1custom/documents",' -e 's,\("$HOME/\)Music",\1custom/music",' -e 's,\("$HOME/\)Pictures",\1custom/pictures",' -e 's,\("$HOME/\)Videos",\1custom/videos",' test_replace.txt
```

and it does this by building up a set of `sed` statements in the array `sed_stmts` which are then used in a single call to `sed`.

The pairing up of the two sets of strings in the two arrays is done by assigning one of the arrays to the list of positional parameters using `set`, and then iterating over the other array.  In each iteration, `shift` is used to shift off the front-most element of the list of positional parameters.